# Unable to get Cognitive Services access token from subscription key

Tags: access-token, azure-cognitive-services

I have tried both key 1 and key 2 from the `Azure Resource Management > Keys` page with the following, where `foo` is a direct copy/paste:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken?Subscription-Key=foo" --data ""

curl -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: foo" --data ""
```

In both cases I get:

```
{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." }
```

Is there something I need to configure so I can I retrieve access tokens for my subscription? My ultimate goal is to use the access token to authenticate with a Custom Speech Service Endpoint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this URL worked instead of the one in the documentation:

`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken`

Here's the complete command:

```
curl -X POST --header "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:foo" --data "" "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken"
```

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation that says https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com so that we can get it fixed.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/API-Reference-REST/BingVoiceRecognition#SpeechService

Comment: Thanks Max.  That URL is for the Speech Recognition API, not the Custom Speech Service.  I believe all of the documentation for Custom Speech Service has westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com, but if you find one that doesn't please let us know.

Comment: Thanks!  FWIW I didn't see any information about how to get an access token on under the Custom Speech Service section of that page https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Custom-Speech-Service/documentation/Home, which is the top search result for "custom speech service microsoft access token"

Comment: That is good feedback Max, I will add this to the list to get fixed.  As our various AI services are coming under a common Cognitive Services platform there are still some improvements needed in documentation and standardization.  You can find the Custom Speech documentation and endpoints at https://cris.ai/Home/Help#Samples.